# Compile issues in Visual Studio, runs fine in Xcode on OSX

Tags: xcode, visual-c++

Me and my friend are working on an assignment together. I use Visual Studio 2013 and he uses Xcode 4 on a macbook. I know it is not optimalto work on two different plattforms but thats how it is. It is an adventure game with many classes an inheritance. He can run the code on his computer without any problems but when I try to compile it I get the following error messages (about 46 of them).

```
error C2436: '{ctor}' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
```

This is a part of the code where Visual Studio says the error happens:

```
Zombie::Zombie() : Character::Character(){

}
```

Anyone has any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no need to use full qualification for the base class constructor. Write that line as `Zombie::Zombie() : Character()`.

Comment: This was actually the answer to my problem, thanks!